# Why doesn't the top half of my outlet work?

Tags: receptacle

Outlet top not working. Has black wire on each brass screw / white wire on each silver screw. Tabs are not broken. No fixtures attach to this. Is this ok?

Answer (score 4):

Outlets wear out (especially the cheap ones). Replace it. Be sure to use good technique. If you don't know good technique, have a look at a house wiring book or other reliable resource.